# Making `get_url` and `unarchive` ansible commands idempotent

Tags: wordpress, ansible

I have two ansible tasks that download an archive (the latest wordpress version, for example) and extract that archive.

```
- name: Download WordPress
  tags:
    - wordpress
    - wordpress:install
  get_url: "url=http://wordpress.org/wordpress-{{ wordpress_version }}.tar.gz dest={{ www_docroot }}/wordpress-{{ wordpress_version }}.tar.gz"

- name: Extract archive
  tags:
    - wordpress
    - wordpress:install
  unarchive:
    src: "{{ www_docroot }}/wordpress-{{ wordpress_version }}.tar.gz"
    dest: "{{ www_docroot }}"
    remote_src: True
```

I'm new to learning ansible and I'm trying to figure out: How can I make this idempotent so that it -

1. Does not download a file if file of the same name already exists or
2. Does not extract / expand the gzip archive if the specified target folder already exists

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consider the **force** option for the first query( `get_url` ) .
consider the **creates** option for the second query( `unarchive` ) .

Sample code, you need something like this?

```
- name: Download WordPress
  tags:
    - wordpress
    - wordpress:install
  get_url: 
    url : "http://wordpress.org/wordpress-{{ wordpress_version }}.tar.gz dest={{ www_docroot }}/wordpress-{{ wordpress_version }}.tar.gz"
    dest: "{{ wordpress_version }}/wordpress-{{ wordpress_version }}.tar.gz"
    force : no
- name: Extract archive
  tags:
    - wordpress
    - wordpress:install
  unarchive:
    src: "{{ www_docroot }}/wordpress-{{ wordpress_version }}.tar.gz"
    dest: "{{ www_docroot }}"
    creates : "{{ www_docroot }}/wordpress"
    remote_src: True
```

Comment: `get_url` use `force: no` by default, so that doesn't change anything in this case

Answer (score 5):

`get_url` module already behaves in the way you want.

You might consider completely skipping the second step if nothing is downloaded on the first step. To achieve that you `register` return value of the first task and check if it is changed in the second with `when`. In your example it will be:

```
- name: Download WordPress
  tags:
    - wordpress
    - wordpress:install
  get_url: "url=http://wordpress.org/wordpress-{{ wordpress_version }}.tar.gz dest={{ www_docroot }}/wordpress-{{ wordpress_version }}.tar.gz"
  register: download_wordpress

- name: Extract archive
  tags:
    - wordpress
    - wordpress:install
  unarchive:
    src: "{{ www_docroot }}/wordpress-{{ wordpress_version }}.tar.gz"
    dest: "{{ www_docroot }}"
    remote_src: True
  when: download_wordpress.changed
```